Remeshing algorithm is doing the same as a slicer software?
I want to check how the parameters of my 3D printer (e.g. layer thickness) influence the geometry of my models (especially the surface details). I have found some resemblance between the remeshed models and the printed objects, but I want to ask whether the remeshing algorithm and the slicer software work in the same basic way?

You didn't tell us what software you are talking about. There are multiple ways of remeshing. What is for you "same basic way" ? They all do the same process yes, given an input mesh, it output another mesh. I think the similarities end there.

I agree with @Lutzi - in goes one mesh, out goes another. That's the similarities. But as far as I know slicer software calculates and adds wall thickness, support structures, print head paths and I don't know what else without thinking harder. While remeshing is just generating a new mesh based on the old mesh and resolution settings according to the method used for remeshing. Simply spoken.

I don't know much about remeshing or slicer softwares. After a quick search on remeshing algorithms, I found that course online (pdf file from Stanford University).
On page 15, it presents 2 fundamental approaches :

So I would say it answers your question.

[Do all remeshing algorithms] work in the same basic way?

No, they don't.

No it doesn't. Remeshing algorithms create a surface, slicing algorithms convert a 3d model into whatever data the printer's hardware needs to work with. They are completely different types of algorithms with different purposes and different designs, completely different context as well and different results - one outputs a mesh another outputs G-code(usually, I assume we are not talking about resin printers).
